# Time complexity 2n^2

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have algorithm that has time complexity of 2n^2, and on some machine it takes x time to execute it. The question is: if my machine is 32 times faster and time stays the same how mutch data will  it process?

ty <3

Comment: There is no way to know that. Knowing the time complexity of an algorithm doesn't give any information on how much input it can process in a given amount of time. Even if you know the amount of data a machine can process in a given time, it doesn't tell you anything about how much data it could process when you speed up the CPU. I've seen similar questions on this site in the past years, and it shows that some teachers do not have a correct understanding of the concept of time complexity.

Comment: Actually, since this is an exact complexity instead of asymptotic, you could predict the running time on an abstract, theoretical processor which always takes the same time for an operation.

Comment: I made mistake in title, it is 2n^2 –

Comment: I suppose the expected interpretation of this question is that "time complexity of 2n^2"  means "the running time is proportional to n^2", and then the answer is "sqrt(32) times more data". As @trincot notes, it is not sound to use time complexity to estimate clock time, and I'd add this is for multiple reasons. I wish there was a well-answered question on "Why can't I estimate running time from time complexity" that this could be marked a duplicate of, since I've seen variations in this questions a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, this question does not make any sense, because complexity does not determine exact runtime, operations etc.

However, here we don't have big-O notation (asymptotic representation), I will work with the assumption that:

1. This is purely theoretical
2. Changing machines doesn't impact time taken per operation (the change remains same across machines and that is exactly by a factor of 32)

So, lets say you process `D`, `d` data points on `M1`, `M2`, taking `x` time

If complexity here represents exact time taken for operations,

```
2 * D^2 = x = 2 * d^2
```

Since M2 is 32 times faster,

```
32 * 2 * D^2 = 2 * d^2
=> d = 4 * D * sqrt(2)
```

Comment: If you find this helpful, accept the answer by clicking on the "green-tick"

Comment: Ty guys, I will check with my professor about formulation of this question But I assume that what vish4071 said is the answer he is seeking for ("32 * 2 * D^2 = 2 * d^2
=> d = 4 * D * sqrt(2)")